# Android - Server communication with mobile apps

Tags: android, server, cloud

Servers will use the cloud.

When I send data from mobile to server, Server will process it and resend.

What skill should I use to communicate with cloud servers in Android?

I am inexperienced in server communications and ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send data to the server you should look into http://square.github.io/retrofit/

If you need the server to be able to push data to the client you can use FCM https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ and create a FirebaseMessagingService

Answer (score 0):

Well, use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

The server can use the REST API or TCP / IP or Google App Engine. Apps can also communicate using these methods. Therefore, specify the desired technology (or usage).

But my suggestion is: Retrofit library.

Comment: I want to send the image file to cloud server so the server process and resend it. But I don't know what technology should I use